How to prevent larger width ranges from applying on exact media query widths?
I have separate ranges for smartphones/tablets/ipads and i have setting for them like 100px width to 500px width , 501px width to 1000px width and so on using a variable .is-smartphone.
and i have no issue with that i am trying to make my web styles on laptops and computers . I have setting for exact screens that are mostly used that i will give below. But still for browser other other screens there should be default styles so i decided to use a big range like "max: 2500px" or "min-width: 100px" but these "max: 2500px" or "min-width: 100px" are applying on exact ranges that it should not. below are my current ranges in which i need to add "max: 2500px" or "min-width: 100px"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 800px) and (min-height: 465px) and (max-height: 465px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 800 * 600 ) --- ---- (actual 800 * 465 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 633px) and (max-height: 633px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1024 * 768 ) --- ---- (actual 1024 * 633 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 585px) and (max-height: 585px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1280 * 720 ) --- ---- (actual 1280 * 585 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 633px) and (max-height: 633px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1280 * 768 ) --- ---- (actual 1280 * 633 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 665px) and (max-height: 665px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1280 * 800 ) --- ---- (actual 1280 * 665 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 685px) and (max-height: 686px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1280 * 1024 ) --- ---- (actual 1024 * 686 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1360px) and (max-width: 1360px) and (min-height: 633px) and (max-height: 633px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1360 * 768 ) --- ---- (actual 1360 * 633 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-height: 633px) and (max-height: 633px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1366 * 768 ) --- ---- (actual 1366 * 633 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1120px) and (max-width: 1120px) and (min-height: 705px) and (max-height: 706px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1400 * 1050 ) --- ---- (actual 1120 * 705 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1440px) and (min-height: 765px) and (max-height: 765px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1440 * 900 ) --- ---- (actual 1440 * 765 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-height: 765px) and (max-height: 765px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1600 * 900 ) --- ---- (actual 1600 * 765 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1344px) and (max-width: 1344px) and (min-height: 705px) and (max-height: 706px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) --- (laptop 1680 * 1050 ) --- ---- (actual 1344 * 705 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) ending */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) starting///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@media only screen and (min-width: 1536px) and (max-width: 1536px) and (min-height: 729px) and (max-height: 730px) { /* laptop screen ( L/P ) starting --- (laptop 1920 * 1080 ) --- ---- (actual 1536 * 730 ) --- */
} /* laptop screen ( L/P ) starting */
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////laptop screen ( L/P ) ending///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Consider replacing max-width with width >=??

Aside from annoying people with excessive horizontal scrolling, it's not clear what this empty CSS file supposed to be showing?

Don’t think ranges, think overrides. All your base style rules should set up your site for mobile devices, following the principle of mobile-first design. Wherever you need change something for wider screens, add @media (min-width: __px) rules in increasing order of width. Ranges are neither necessary nor desirable.
.class {
  /* mobile declarations first */
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .class {
    /* tablet overrides */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .class {
    /* desktop overrides */
  }
}

Of course you can set your min-widths to any values you like, but I find that 750px and 1000px are easy to remember and the most useful ones to use. 500px is also useful if you need to override anything for phones held sideways.

Phones in portrait orientation are typically narrower than 500px
Phones in landscape orientation are typically between 500px and 750px in width
Tablets in portrait orientation are typically between 750px and 1000px in width
Tablets in landscape orientation are typically wider than 1000px
Laptops and desktops are also typically wider than 1000px, but you can keep adding additional media rules if you want to cater specifically for very wide screens.

